# Event for class / method / Interface

Tags: c#

I try to make a custom event, if my properties are changed in myVariable class, but in each example I have to do it for each value. Is it not possible to trigger on the write Interface or Method?

Propertyclass

```
public sealed class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int Pid { get; set; }
    public int Tid { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

My Interface

```
public interface ILogObserver
{
    void NewEntry(LogEntry entry);
    void NewData(string[] data, int size);
}
```

If one of these both methods are called I would like to fire a event, if data has been changed. Could somebody support me?

Comment: How do you determine if data has changed? What exactly is the problem you are facing? Raising the event?

Comment: You have to implement the code that fires the event in each of the methods that is supposed to fire the event. Typically you add a call to `OnSomethingSomething` in those methods, but no, you cannot get that code automatically through the interface.

Comment: There is a fab package to do this automatically for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/

Comment: Thank you Maarten. The nuget package looks what i searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use existing interface for this - `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Here's [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on it.

Here's preview that uses this interface, see link for full example.

```
// This is a simple customer class that 
// implements the IPropertyChange interface.
public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // These fields hold the values for the public properties.
    private Guid idValue = Guid.NewGuid();
    private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
    private string phoneNumberValue = String.Empty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern.
    private DemoCustomer()
    {
        customerNameValue = "Customer";
        phoneNumberValue = "(312)555-0100";
    }

    // This is the public factory method.
    public static DemoCustomer CreateNewCustomer()
    {
        return new DemoCustomer();
    }

    // This property represents an ID, suitable
    // for use as a primary key in a database.
    public Guid ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idValue;
        }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneNumberValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
            {
                this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this example too. Do I have really to put it in each set property? Is it not possible to cluster all properties and then fire on change?